# Can't use qualifiers with interface that consist generics

Tags: java, generics, jakarta-ee, cdi, qualifiers

Met situation when cdi with qualifier and generics doesn't work.

For example, i have interface like this:

```
public interface SomeInterface<T> {
   T someMethod(Set<T> set);
}
```

Its implementation (and several another implementations with another qualifiers):

```
@SomeQualifier
public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface<AnotherClass> {
    AnotherClass someMethod(Set<AnotherClass> set) {...some logic...}
}
```

And some qualifier like this:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface SomeQualifier {}
```

So, when i inject its in some bean (singleton in my project) :

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class SomeSingleton {
  @Inject
  @SomeQualifier
  SomeInterface instance;

  ..usage...
}
```

i got exception in deploy process like

```
Unsatisfied dependencies for type SomeInterface with qualifiers @SomeQualifier
```

But when i use all of that without using generics - all works fine!

Tried injecting like this:

```
@Inject
@SomeQualifier
SomeInterface<AnotherClass> instance;
```

Got same result.

Any idea how can i use inject with qualifiers and generics?

Comment: `SomeInterface instance` is raw. The non-raw `SomeInterface<AnotherClass>` doesn't match that.

Comment: So, can i inject that using interface at all?

Comment: Presumably you can with `@Inject @SomeQualifier SomeInterface<AnotherClass> instance`?

Comment: as i wrote i tried that and got exception like this:
Unsatisfied dependencies for type SomeInterface<AnotherClass> with qualifiers @SomeQualifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your first approach doesn't work is because you are violating [CDI spec assignability rules](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#assignable_parameters) (the very first line). In short - injecting raw type only works for unbound/`Object` types.

However, the **second approach does work - I just verified in with Weld SE**. E.g.:

```
@Inject
@SomeQualifier
SomeInterface<AnotherClass> instance;
```

I suppose you might have forgotten to recompile your code or something? Double check that because I am certain this works. That, or you have some other problem in the code.

Comment: Yeah, i tried it again and now it works... maybe i forgot some annotations earlier. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I have recreated the samples, and it should work as expected.

Qualifiers:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER})
public @interface BasicSample {
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER})
public @interface IntegerSample {
}
```

The implementations:

```
public interface SampleGenericInterface<T> {

    T process(Set<T> values);

}
```

And two implementations:

```
@BasicSample
@ApplicationScoped
public class BasicSampleGenericInterface implements SampleGenericInterface<BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal process(Set<BigDecimal> values) {
        return values.stream().max(BigDecimal::compareTo).orElse(null);
    }

}


@IntegerSample
@ApplicationScoped
public class IntegerSampleGenericInterface implements SampleGenericInterface<Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer process(Set<Integer> values) {
        return values.stream().min(Integer::compareTo).orElse(null);
    }

}
```

And a test class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class CdiTest {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CdiTest.class.getName());

    @Inject
    @BasicSample
    private SampleGenericInterface<BigDecimal> bigDecimalSampleGenericInterface;

    @Inject
    @IntegerSample
    private SampleGenericInterface<Integer> integerSampleGenericInterface;

    void start(@Observes ContainerInitialized containerInitialized) {
        Set<BigDecimal> bigDecimals = new HashSet<>();
        bigDecimals.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(837373));
        bigDecimals.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(8299));
        bigDecimals.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(4545454));
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Big Decimal: {0}", bigDecimalSampleGenericInterface.process(bigDecimals));
        Set<Integer> integers = new HashSet<>();
        integers.add(72);
        integers.add(3452);
        integers.add(458923);
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Integers: {0}", integerSampleGenericInterface.process(integers));
    }
}
```

You can copy this class and run it as:

> java org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain

During resolution, the generic parameters and qualifier annotations will be taken into considerations.